# USB Serial Virtual COM Port : Read not working but write works

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, usb, virtual-serial-port

I use embedded hardware (by TI : Piccolo Control Stick xxx69) which uses FTDI usb to serial converter hardware.

On PC, I have simple VC++ application which tries to communicate to hardware over Virtual COM port (VCOM : typically COM7).

- I am able to connect to port properly.
- I am able to send data from application/PC to hardware and it is received correctly. (So, Tx on PC is working fine), Application first opens the connection using `createfile(... ... ...)` API and then uses `writefile(.. ... ..)` windows apis to write into the port directly.
- SURPRISINGLY, I am not able to read from serial port to application. When I call `readfile(... ... ...)` api, it returns status as TRUE but ZERO bytes are read. I tried using API monitor software, which shows kernel api `Ntreadfile(... ... ...)`, returns error as `STATUS_TIMEOUT" [0x00000102]`. It is surprising, because write works but read doesn't although data is there on line.

Data is on the line, because when I use normal hyper-terminal software, I am able to read the data correctly form controller and it is visible. [On controller side, it is all right because we can see data on hyper-terminal.

I am not windows programmer, as I deal with micro-controllers. Therefore, some help in terms to pursue this issue would be of great help.

Best Regards,

-Varun

Here is a [Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b65e4ff9-a7ce-4818-8e36-9db75fe8f49f/usb-serial-virtual-com-port-read-not-working?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: This is entirely normal.  It takes a programmer to modify the SetCommTimeouts() call in the program.

Comment: Hans, SetCommTimeouts() is not used in my write function. [although ia am using a legacy code which was developed for VC6 ]. Do you think timeouts matter only for reads... BTW, I had increased the timeout from device registry entries, then call waited for specified time but result was still ZERO bytes read. Please elaborate on your hint if possible!

Comment: Registry entry place: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_A6D0+TIU81CWRB\0000\Device Parameters : MinReadTimeout

Comment: Guys, Issue is solved. I had to add wait till InQueue > 0 (it means there is atleast 1 byte in receive buffer) or timeout is over. it would be blocking call but it is OK for my application at the moment. waitComm() did not work well for me here.

Comment: Don"t hesitate to answer your own question. That way people coming here from google or seeing the question in a list on stackoverflow can now that the question is answered.

Comment: thanks Etienne for msg, actually i posted same as comment but did not knew about adding same as answer. I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved. I had to add wait till InQueue > 0 (it means there is atleast 1 byte in receive buffer) or timeout (as safety exit) is over. it would be blocking call but it is OK for my application at the moment. waitComm() did not work well for me here.

sample snippet:

```
while(1)
    {
        ClearCommError((HANDLE)*h_drv, (LPDWORD)&Err, &CST);

        if((CST.cbInQue >0)||(count >1000000))
        break;

        count++;
    }
```